# Publishing MVC app on web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-publishing

I am trying to publish my app on the web. It is very simple app, I have just start to learn MVC. To publish my app I have followed the instructions given at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis. However I cannot see app from other PCs. I see it in browser from the PC where I have created it, but when I try to open it from another PC it is not visible, the link I am trying to access is the one I created during publishing - http:/localhost/WebApplication1. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Or maybe the example I followed is not correct for the thing I want to do. Could,please someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `localhost` is the address of the local machine (host). Use your PC's name or IP address instead

Comment: Thank you so much for such quick response. Could you please tell me is there a way to publish it on the web, so I can see it from other PCs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you publish your site on localhost, you'll see it only in your local network. To publish it on the web, you'll need some web hosting service. You can try, for example, Microsoft Azure, it works perfectly with ASP.NET (not too surprisingly, as it comes from Microsoft), has a 30 day free trial period and otherwise is relatively cheap for low usage.